# AngularJS controller.. Why the code id not working?

Tags: angularjs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-ng-app="myApp" data-ng-controller="SimpleController">
    <h3>Adding a Simple Controller</h3> 
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="demons"/> {{demons}}
    <ul>
        <li data-ng-repeat="foo in ManiacArray | orderBy: 'name'">{{foo.name | uppercase }} => {{foo.state | lowercase }}</li>    
    </ul>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var app = angular.module(myApp, []);
    app.controller('SimpleController' function($scope){
        $scope.ManiacArray = [
        {name: 'Akshay Raina', state: 'Jammu Kashmir'},
        {name: 'Vikram Kaintura', state: 'Uttarakhand'},
        {name: 'Ronak Furia', state: 'Gujarat'},
        {name: 'Bhagyashree Shetty', state: 'Manglore'},
        {name: 'Bhavna Kamble', state: 'Maharashtra'},
        {name: 'Navin Tiwari', state: 'Uttar Pradesh'},
        {name: 'Nikung Mishra', state: 'Bihar'},
        {name: 'Ashish Natani', state: 'Rajasthan'},
        {name: 'Malaya Dalai', state: 'Orrisa'},
        {name: 'Pearl D\'mello', state: 'Goa'},
        ];
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I am not sure why this isn't working..
I tried fixing.. but i failed..
i am at learning stage so couldn't figure out whats going wrong with this..

Comment: load jquery before angular.min.js

Comment: Just open console, and check error..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Replace `var app = angular.module(myApp, []);` with

   `var app = angular.module("myApp", []);`
2. Replace `app.controller('SimpleController' function($scope){` with
   `app.controller('SimpleController', function($scope){`

New code,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-ng-app="myApp" data-ng-controller="SimpleController">
    <h3>Adding a Simple Controller</h3> 
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="demons"/> {{demons}}
    <ul>
        <li data-ng-repeat="foo in ManiacArray | orderBy: 'name'">{{foo.name | uppercase }} => {{foo.state | lowercase }}</li>    
    </ul>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
    app.controller('SimpleController', function($scope){
        $scope.ManiacArray = [
        {name: 'Akshay Raina', state: 'Jammu Kashmir'},
        {name: 'Vikram Kaintura', state: 'Uttarakhand'},
        {name: 'Ronak Furia', state: 'Gujarat'},
        {name: 'Bhagyashree Shetty', state: 'Manglore'},
        {name: 'Bhavna Kamble', state: 'Maharashtra'},
        {name: 'Navin Tiwari', state: 'Uttar Pradesh'},
        {name: 'Nikung Mishra', state: 'Bihar'},
        {name: 'Ashish Natani', state: 'Rajasthan'},
        {name: 'Malaya Dalai', state: 'Orrisa'},
        {name: 'Pearl D\'mello', state: 'Goa'},
        ];
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things are wrong:

1. This line `var app = angular.module(myApp, []);` 
   should be `var app = angular.module("myApp", []);` You need to initialize a module with a string.
2. In you controller you miss a comma:
   `app.controller('SimpleController', function($scope){`

Comment: @Godric Gryffindor why did you downvote this. it is correct